# Retrieve Email templates from Salesforce Marketing cloud (SFMC) using SOAP or REST api

Tags: marketing-cloud

How to retrieve Email templates from Salesforce Marketing cloud (SFMC) using SOAP or REST api?
I am able to create simple template using FUELSDK  but not able to retrieve it. I am using FuelSDK for java.

Answer (score 1):

REST API is for Content Builder Email, SOAP API is for classic Email.

I assume you are referring to class Email? you need to send a [RetrieveRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieverequest.htm) for [Template](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/template.htm) Object in SOAP API to get template objects

If you want specific templates, you can use [SimpleFilter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/simplefilterpart.htm) or [ComplexFilter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/complexfilterpart.htm) to filter the results

Comment: I am not referring to Email class. I want to write a code to retrieve Template. I have tried using RetrieveRequest class. Retrieve method takes ETApiObject as a parameter. There is no ETTemplate class available in java FuelSDK. I could retrieve all other things that are avaliable as ETApiObjects like Email , Folder etc. But not template.

Comment: @Nishi I do mean the templates in classic email view, not content builder. If Template object is not available for retrieve in fuelsdk, you can send soap request directly in java code, this is doc for Email object but you can do setobjecttype(“Template”) https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_an_email_via_the_soap_api.htm